# Luby-Rackoff theorem for Generalized Feistel

Tags: block-cipher, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation, feistel-network

I was reading about Luby-Rackoff theorem from various sources: [[1](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/prp.html)], [[2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48489/why-do-feistel-ciphers-need-round-keys?)], [[3](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35351/need-for-3-rounds-in-luby-rackoff-theorem)], which says you need at least 3 rounds of a $2$-branch Feistel network to get a PRP if the underlying $f$ function is a PRF. I also came to know about the [Generalized Feistel Network](http://cryptowiki.net/index.php?title=Generalized_Feistel_networks) which has more than two branches.

What will be the minimum number of rounds to get a PRP from a generalized $n~(>2)$ branch Feistel network, given the underlying function $f$ is a PRF?

Comment: Ah, OK, I think I'm starting to see the idea of the question now.  It asks for the number of rounds as a function of $n$, given that the PRF is theoretically secure. Thanks, I'll remove the other comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably saw in the reference linked, there are multiple types of "basic" generalized Feistel networks: Type-1, Type-2 and Type-3. As far as I can tell all of these were introduced at [CRYPTO'89 by Zheng, Matsumoto, and Imai in *"On the Construction of Block Ciphers Provably Secure and Not Relying on Any Unproved Hypotheses"*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-387-34805-0_42).

Suppose that your state is split into $k$ blocks, then the above paper does in fact prove  / claim security for these generalized Feistel constructions (with each and every PRF used in all rounds and all state parts of each round being independent):

- For Type-1, security is proven for $2k-1$ rounds
- For Type-2, security is proven for $k+1$ rounds
- For Type-3, security is proven for $k+1$ rounds

The paper also proves / claims that these numbers of rounds are actually minimal.

For everbody's reference, here are the three basic types as a fancy graphic: [image: Feistel variants]
<sup>[image source](http://cryptowiki.net/index.php?title=File:%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A4028_e.JPG)</sup>

As one can somewhat clearly see, the first two types are "special cases" of the third where a certain selections of PRF invocations and XORings is dropped. The paper does provide further analysis on the number of rounds to keep security when dropping these with certain patterns